# How to show large dataset legends properly for flot chart?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, flot

In my flot chart when data is too large, legend does not fit properly in the chart view, so I decided to make legend appear in a outer container, but looks like flot creates a table td elements in 1 row and legend is not wrapping inside the div. Also somehow my stacking does not seem to work well, is there a data issue?

Data format

```
[{
    "data": [
        [1415059200000, 2],
        [1415145600000, 2],
        [1415318400000, 1],
        [1415577600000, 1],
        [1415750400000, 1],
        [1415923200000, 3],
        [1416009600000, 1],
        [1416096000000, 1],
        [1416182400000, 1],
        [1416873600000, 2],
        [1416960000000, 2],
        [1418342400000, 2]
    ],
    "label": "Neeraj_secure",
    "bars": {
        "show": "true",
        "barWidth": 36000000,
        "fillColor": "#46CEAD",
        "order": 1,
        "align": "center"
    },
    "stack": true
}]
```

html container

```
<div id="adoptionLegendContainer"></div>
<flot dataset="tasksRunData" options="tasksRunChartOptions" class="center-block" width="100%" height="400px" min="reportTasksRunRange.min" max="reportTasksRunRange.max"></flot>
```

chart option

```
xaxis: {
    mode: "time",
    timeformat: "%m/%d/%y",
    minTickSize: [1, "day"]
  },
  grid: {
    labelMargin: 10,
    hoverable: true,
    borderWidth: 0
  },
  series: {
    stack: true
  },
  colors: colorCodes,
  tooltip: true,
    legend: {
        show: true,
        noColumns: 0, // number of colums in legend table
        labelFormatter: null, // fn: string -> string
        labelBoxBorderColor: "#888", // border color for the little label boxes
        container: "#adoptionLegendContainer", // container (as jQuery object) to put legend in, null means default on top of graph
        position: "nw", // position of default legend container within plot
        margin: [5, 10], // distance from grid edge to default legend container within plot
        backgroundOpacity: 0 // set to 0 to avoid background
    }
```

Please help. I am providing a [plunker link here](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZAk9Hf76gn4oNcZTWBtl?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

You can set `display: inline-block` to the table cells inside the container `#adoptionLegendContainer` through CSS.

```
#adoptionLegendContainer { height: 200px; overflow: auto;}
#adoptionLegendContainer td {display: inline-block;}
#adoptionLegendContainer td.legendColorBox{margin: 0 5px;}
```

The issue with this is at times you may find the color box as the last one and its label on next line.

[Plunkr Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/njzYuXdr9xrXAFpvbbaG?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks this kind of solves my problem. Also is my data format correct for bar stacking, because I see irregular hover changes in chart!

Comment: Looks ok to me. What is the hover issue you are talking about?

Comment: Modified my [plunker link](http://plnkr.co/edit/pt4u99pi1rD7VTR24fvl?p=preview) to include tooltip which shows 1st xaxis data has 2 points 1 & 2 respectively .. looks like 2 is overlapping 1, ideally it should show the bar height should be till 3 (1+2)

Comment: Not sure if  I got you. For stacking to work you need to include the stack js too. [Check now](http://plnkr.co/edit/cdjoDxJu3tVgo2XBH3sz?p=preview)

Comment: I guess you need to have the entries for all dates to remove the overlap. You can make it as 0 tasks if it's not there but there should be an entry. [Check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TPp8m/86/) and follow the instruction in the CSS window.

Answer (score 0):

There is already a line in your plot options to address this issue:

```
            noColumns: 0, // number of colums in legend table
```

Change this to a reasonable number and you get a nicer legend:

```
            noColumns: 5, // number of colums in legend table
```

[updated plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Zj2MyscAOzbSnmwy5Owl?p=preview)

Comment: But then it will always remain same and when I resize my browser it will not change.

Comment: You can calculate the number of columns in relation to the new width in your resize-event code before redrawing the chart.

Comment: Thanks, can you give a small snippet to start with?